# Block value in a view row design template

Tags: views, theming

I have a block value which I need to access in a views row design template. I need to check the value of the block content in this template.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
$block = block_custom_block_get($block_id);
$content = $block['body'];
```

But be advised that it would generally contain html which would be difficult to parse.

If you are looking to store a value and then use it to check in the theme layer I would suggest creating an admin page for that and storing the value in the variables table, which you can later access by

```
variable_get('my_setting', 3);
```